# How do I tell iTunes to NOT mark podcasts as "Skip when shuffling" by default?

Tags: itunes, music, podcasts, smart-playlist

I have a Smart Playlist that selects a set of music and podcasts for me to listen to throughout the day. However, iTunes decides it's a good idea to check the **"Skip when shuffling"** checkbox for all podcasts the moment it downloads them:

[image: The Nerdist podcast, with "Skip when shuffling" checked.]

My current workaround is unchecking these manually for each podcast, and does indeed include them when playing the playlist, but this is obviously not a permanent fix. **Is there any way to tell iTunes that is's OK to play podcasts when shuffling by default?**

Comment: Possibly related to an older Apple discussion, [_Smart playlist of "Media Kind is Podcast" not syncing to iPad_](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3080182?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: [Cross-posted to Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7230534)